# Ant script to execute Soap UI Mock and Soap UI Test suite

Tags: soap, ant, jenkins

I want to integrate soup ui project to jenkins. I have a test suite and a mock service , The mock service should be running in order to test the test suite.

I wrote a build script to execute the mock service first and then the test case. The following is the script

```
<project  name="test" default="DIAG_COMPLETE" basedir=".">
   <property name="project" value="./Complete--soapui-project.xml" />

   <target name="DIAG_COMPLETE" depends="DIAG" >
    <exec executable="D:\Soapui\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\testrunner.bat" failonerror="false" failifexecutionfails="false" >
         <arg line="-sdiag_upload_tc -rja -f./reports ${project}"/>
      </exec>
   </target>

  <!-- invokes the mock service -->
    <target name="DIAG" >
        <exec executable="D:\Soapui\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\mockservicerunner.bat" failonerror="false" failifexecutionfails="false" >
            <arg line="-m'DBDiagnosticDataTransmissionSOAPBinding MockService' -p8088 -a/mockDBDiagnosticDataTransmissionSOAPBinding -b ${project}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>  
</project>
```

I am not sure if this is the write approach.

Only if this works fine, I can integrate it with jenkins.
and this does not work because the mock service is not getting started.

I want an approach to proceed further in my jenkins integration.

Thanks Jacob Marshell